# Webpack watch compiles my scss sass but not webpack-dev-server

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass, babeljs, webpack-hmr

I am able to compile my sass successfully with webpack using the `webpack --watch` command, but it does not perform hot module replacement.

I am able to do HMR successfully with the `webpack-dev-server --hot --progress --colors --inline` command, and it reloads with my `.js` changes, but not my `.scss`/`.css` ones.

I've noticed that when I change a sass file the server refreshes, but the styles aren't updated. I want to make sure I'm doing it with just one command.

Here's the scripts from my package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack -p",
    "watch": "webpack --watch",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot --progress --colors --inline"
  },
```

and here's my entire webpack config:

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    master: "./src/index.jsx"
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "[name].js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: "style-loader",
          use: ["css-loader", "sass-loader"],
          publicPath: "dist"
        })
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: "babel-loader"
      },
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx"]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: "master.css",
      allChunks: true
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
    hot: true,
    port: 3000,
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    inline: true,
    disableHostCheck: true,
  }
};
```

and, in case it's necessary, here's my .babelrc (I'm using React):

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
    "react-hot-loader/babel"
  ]
}
```

How do I get my webpack dev server to reload with my compiled sass changes as I change them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually figured this out with the following setup. I think the issue was related to the fact that both watch and webpack dev server were in the webpack config - and I realized that watch mode is not needed in my setup if I'm running webpack dev server:

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    master: "./src/index.jsx"
  },
  watch: true,
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "[name].js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["babel-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: "style-loader",
          use: ["css-loader", "sass-loader"],
          publicPath: "dist"
        })
      },

    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx"]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: "master.css",
      allChunks: true
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
    hot: true,
    port: 3000,
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    inline: true,
    disableHostCheck: true,
    watchOptions: {
      ignored: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')
      ]
    }
  }
};
```

and package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server",
    "dist": ""
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can view my full config [here](https://github.com/SaiGonSoftware/Awesome-CMS-Core/blob/master/src/AwesomeCMSCore/AwesomeCMSCore/webpack.config.js)

```
plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: "[name].css",
        chunkFilename: "[id].css"
    })
],
module: {
    rules: [{
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [
                'style-loader',
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                {
                    loader: "css-loader",
                    options: {
                        minimize: true,
                        sourceMap: true
                    }
                },
                {
                    loader: "sass-loader"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```